Variable Font Weight Doesn't Change Font Weight
I am having trouble getting a variable font to work in Overleaf. For context, I downloaded the EBGaramond Font from Google Fonts. After adding the corresponding files to my Overleaf Project, I ran the following code:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EBGaramond-VariableFont}[Path = ./, 
    Extension = .ttf, 
    ItalicFont = EBGaramond-Italic-VariableFont, 
    Ligatures=TeX
]

\begin{document}

\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+axis={wght=100}}} Light Text

\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+axis={wght=400}}} Medium Text

\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+axis={wght=700}}} Hard text

\end{document}

However, my output contains text that looks the same:

I tried searching code online, asking ChatGPT, and visited this related post but still can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you for the help!

\defaultfontfeatures{RawFeature={+axis={wght=100}}} just sets up the defaults if you later declare a font but you neither declare nor select any font

Ah ok changing to \addfontfeatures made it work. I am beginning to understand how fonts work a bit better. Thank you for the help!

it is usually best (and a lot more efficient) to avoid such declarations in the body of the document and just declare \normalseries  \boldseries and (say) \lightseries  in the preamble so you can then switch between pre-declared font weighst using normal latex commands.
